# Probability of an Ace at the 2nd card take

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Problem :
An experiment consists of removing the top card from a well shuffled pack of 52 playing cards. Calculate the probability that (a) the first card is an ace, (b) the next card is an ace.

---

Attempt:
The (a) is quite simple, there are only 4 aces, so the probability that I get an ace at first attempt is $4/52=1/13$.

The (b) part, we can see that if the first one is not an ace, then there are 48 choices, for the 1st take, and 4 ace choices for the 2nd take. So the probability is $$ \frac{48 \times 4}{52 \times 51} $$

---

But the answer key for (b) says the probability is $1/13$. If we look in different point of view, say a stack of 52 cards after a shuffle, then the probability that the card at the 2nd place on top is an ace is $1/13$.

Is my analysis accuratr or not? Thanks.

Comment: What if the first card you chose was an ace, and the second one was also an ace?

Comment: You failed to account for the case where the first card is an ace. You can then use conditioning to get the right answer. But the best way to do this is to observe both probabilities are the same, so for (b) simply write down $1/13$.

Comment: In b) you are asked to find the probability that the second card is an ace. **Not** the probability that the first card is not an ace and the second card is an ace.

Comment: Thanks @LordSharktheUnknown I thought that the book meant with the first card is not an ace.. because there is actually a c) part which ask the prpbability of two aces at first two attempts.

Comment: Thanks @drhab I thought that the book meant with the first card is not an ace.. because there is actually a c) part which ask the prpbability of two aces at first two attempts.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your reasoning is okay, but the first card may be an ace, *or* it may not.

- The probability that the first is an ace and so is the second is $\tfrac {4}{52}\tfrac{3}{51}$
- The probability that the first is something else and the second is and ace is $\tfrac {48}{52}\tfrac{4}{51}$

You need to add them together (re: Law of Total Probability) to get the probability that the second card is an ace whatever the first may be.   And since $3+48$ conveniently equals $51$... the result is :$$=\dfrac 1{13}$$

As anticipated.

Hey, now, what is the probability that the fifteenth card down the deck is an ace?

Comment: Thanks. I think the probability is the same $1/13$. We can look as the probability of getting an ace when choosing the 15th spot above the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

If cards are randomly placed in a row and have received numbers $1,2,\dots,52$ then what is the probability that e.g. the card with number $37$ is an ace?

Are there any reasons to think that it will differ from the probability that the card with number e.g. $13$ (or $1$, or $2$ if you like) will be an ace?

Comment: Thanks. I think the probability is the same 1/13. We can look as the probability of getting an ace when choosing the 13th spot.

Comment: Correct. Every spot of the $52$ spots has the same chance to be linked with an ace.